# Fullpage.js sticky header background color change when scrolling

Tags: fullpage.js, elementor

I have fullpage.js working perfectly as I want it to. Also already got my header to be sticky. It starts transparent and when you scroll its background turns white. Thing is that when I enable fullpage.js it is as if the header was not detecting any scroll and therefore even though it stays sticky the background color does not change.

I have tested various settings to see if they work but none have yet worked. Im completely new to coding.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //options here
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
    autoScrolling: true,
    navigation: true,
    slidesNavigation: true, 
    css3: false,
    fitToSection: true,
    fitToSectionDelay: 0,
    scrollBar: false,
    lazyLoading: true,
    menu: true

});
//methods
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
$("#navigation").sticky({topSpacing:0}).css({'background':'#000'});
```

});

I want that when the fullpage.js scrolls the header changes color. It currently does not detect any scrolling. Im sorry if this is too basic. Im just trying to learn and thanks!

Comment: I think a example would be nice, here is what I would like to achieve. 
https://zientte.com/

The way the header changes when scrolling down.

Comment: How are you using fullPage.js in elementor? Any plugin?

Comment: Well I really am just putting the css with a plugin. Custom CSS and JS. The thing is that by reading every related post to this the scroll option is basically disabled if you have autoscroll: true and scrollBar: true. I cant use any of those because they make the scrolling quirky which defeats the purpose of fullpage.js.

I have seen the video and though it is really clear and I understand the process I dont really know how to use the state classes to achieve what I need.

When I inspect the body it shows a really long body class, should i use that entire class to target the body? Thanks

Comment: Could not properly thank you Alvaro in the previous post. Thank you very much. The plugin rocks! will definitely use it with newer projects and implement extensions :)

Comment: You just need to use the class `fp-viewing-X-Y` where `X` is the section anchor and `Y` the slide anchor. Same as I explained in the video. You can use those classes to fire CSS conditions. 
`scrollBar:true` shouldn't be quirky, in fact, the [scrollBar:true demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) works as expected. Perhaps your page is very heavy for it and is binding way too many things in the scroll event?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions) you'll need to use `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false` if you want to rely on the scroll event.

Otherwise, you should be using [fullPage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or [state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) to deal with those changes of state.

You can check [my video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&t=7s) regarding how to use the fullpage.js state classes to trigger changes in state.